# How to use Tablesorter's numberSorter?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I need to sort numbers in column so that negative numbers always sorted under positive numbers. Read that it can be done with help of numberSorter property but I don't find any example with it.
For example wen I sort ascending it sorts like this:
1
2
3
4
5
6
-1
-2
-3
And when I sort descending it sorts like this:
6
5
4
3
2
1
-3
-2
-1

Their example:

```
$(function(){
    $("table").tablesorter({
        numberSorter : function(a, b, direction, maxColumnValue){
            // direction; true = ascending; false = descending
            // maxColumnValue = the maximum value of that column (ignoring its sign)
            return a - b;
        }
    });
});
```

gives me error: **TypeError: x is undefined**

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like you found a bug. This line ([732](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js#L732)):

```
sort = c.numberSorter ? c.numberSorter(x[col], y[col], dir, colMax[col], table) :
```

should actually look like this (replace x & y with a & b, respectively)

```
sort = c.numberSorter ? c.numberSorter(a[col], b[col], dir, colMax[col], table) :
```

Then once you do that you can use this numberSorting script ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2226/)).

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    numberSorter: function (a, b, direction) {
        if (a >= 0 && b >= 0) { return direction ? a - b : b - a; }
        if (a >= 0) { return -1; }
        if (b >= 0) { return 1; }
        return direction ? b - a : a - b;
    }
});
```

Comment: Bug fixed in version 2.15.10. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   // add parser through the tablesorter addParser method 
    $.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'mySortingFunction', 
        is: function(s) { 
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return false; 
        }, 
        format: function(s) { 
            // your logic
            return s; 
        }, 
        // set type, either numeric or text 
        type: 'numeric' 
    }); 

$(function() { 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            6: { 
                sorter:'mySortingFunction' 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

6 it's the column number you want to sort with custom mySortingFunction (you'll need to change it).

Comment: In order to get my negative numbers sorted ALWAYS under positive numbers I need direction (desc or asc) but in parser I don't have it...

Comment: Add a global    var countAsc = 1and before "return s" add a "countAsc = 1 - countAsc". Wrap the logic in "if (countAsc > 0) {//asc logic} else {//desc logic}". You don't need really asc or desc, you need just to alternate your sorting. However if you are able to assign a value (numeric) to a string, you don't need this workaround.
Ex: return s.toLowerCase().replace(/great/,3).replace(/normal/,2).replace(/poor/,1);

Comment: I don't really understand what great, normal and poor can help me with?

Comment: I didn't got the point. Well, your problem probably it's that you didn't declared in "header" options col as "digit" so tablesorter treat numbers as string